# Access Tomcat root application under different path (on AWS/Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are deploying a webapp (.war file) from a legacy system where we have full control over our Tomcat instances to Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk instances.

On our own systems, we access the web app as a path (e.g. `http://server-name/my-app` if we deploy my-app.war), but Elastic Beanstalk renames our war-file to ROOT.war and hence makes the web app available under `http://server-name`, which breaks our existing applications.

As per the AWS documentation, we have added a config file under `WEB-INF/.ebextensions` that copies the following custom `context.xml`-file to `/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context displayName="localhost" docBase="" path="/my-app">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

We have tried different versions of this file, e.g. omitting docBase, specifying `docBase="ROOT"`, using the `aliases` parameter etc., providing the full path to the ROOT directory etc., but none has made our WAR-file accessible under the `/my-app` path.

Finally, we also tried putting this `<Context />`-definition under the `<Host />` section in `server.xml`, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

*Update*: when adding the following to `server.xml` under the `<Host/>`-definition, I'm able to access `my-app` under the correct path, but it seems that Tomcat on EB is deploying my application twice now:

```
<Context path="/my-app" docBase="ROOT/"></Context>
```

Comment: I have been stuck at this problem for like 3 days now. I am not sure what to do. Locally i can access my app and REST services using context root but when deployed on aws instance it is not available. Where can i find server.xml? And pointer to any documentation will be helpful. Also i was able to connect to my instance using putty but i cannot find the path /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml

Comment: @breght so, what was the result? I'm facing exactly the same issue and I don't get if I have to create a `context.xml` or a `server.xml`, and what content it has to have :·) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we can now access our app under the desired path, the application is still deployed twice by Tomcat. While this is a minor nuisance for us, I can imagine this being a problem on more resource-tight machines. On the plus side, we can now start migrating our apps to no longer use the resource path when accessing the API, which leads to cleaner and shorter API URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's two years late. But seems like disabling deployOnStartup will do the work.

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false">
```